# Different currencies inside one ICO

Tags: contract-development, tokens, ico

We create a mapping when creating a token to link donator addresses to the sum of tokens that belongs to this user. This mapping contains addresses which are ETH wallet addresses.

Piece of this mapping can be interpreted like this string:

```
0x1234567 => 50 //that means ETH address 0x1234567 has 50 tokens
```

My question is: most of ICOs accept both ETH and BTC donations, so how do they organize that main token mapping if ETH and BTC have different addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BTC or other currencies - Be it fiat or other cryptocurrencies- can not be handled inside an Ethereum smart contract.

The ICOs that do have smart contracts in place and that accept currencies other than Ether, what they do is to add a function in the smart contract where the owner can "invest" on behalf of the contributor.

So basically what you would do is to accept money off-chain and then issue the tokens to them using this function only a available to you.

Comment: Also it is possible to accept bitcoin through btcrelay and usually the values are converted from BTC to ETH with an oracle or something similar.

Comment: So if I want to buy tokens with BTC I still need to provide ETH address? In order to assign provided sum of tokens to a particular address.

Comment: Yes, tokens should always be assigned to an ETH address, if not, there's no way for the owner to access them on their wallet.
You can do the transaction as I mentioned in my answer, or you can do what @Ismael suggests.